# Is it possible to show only the folder and files that one user is allowed to see in a common folder?

Tags: windows

I have a common folder that is Data. In this folder I have some shared folder and another private folders, one for each user.

I would like to know if there is some way that when a user enter in the folder data, it only could see the folder that it is allowed to see, that it would be its personal folder and the shared folder in which it can enter. But I don't want that it can see which another folder there are, for another users, for example.

I have tried to give for all users, read permissions for the data folder, and I select applies only for this folder. So it will not propagate the permissions for the child folders.

Then for the personal folder, I give only permission to the user. In this way, other users can't access, but still they can see in the file explorer.

But I don't see another way to can do that. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that the problem you are having is one of basic understanding.  Think of the `Data` folder as a file with records in it (which it is).  Some of those records point to files.. some to other sub-directories.  Either a user can read that folder record or they can't.. there is no way (that I am aware of) to let a user read only *part* of a directory entry.  Yes, folders other users can see but can't enter is the way to go.

Comment: Is "access-based enumeration" of interest - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/enable-access-based-enumeration-on-a-namespace

Comment: I know about ABE (access based enumeration), but it seems it can affect to performance. I would prefer don't use this option.